# auto-redirecting page is skipped by Chrome history

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, frontend

I have a webpage url1 that will do auto-redirecting to url2 with `window.location.href`. However, when I click "back" button on Chrome, I am redirected to the page before url1, url1 is skipped. But I can still back to url1 by `window.history.back()`. This problem doesn't happen in FireFox. Any help?

Answer (score 3):

It's Chrome feature since Chrome 75, named **History manipulation intervention**. History without a user interaction will be skipped when a user hits Chrome back button.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=907167