# How to Avoid Page_Load When Users Arrive at Certain Pages Using Browser Back/Forward Buttons

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, navigation, .net-4.8

I want to redirect the user to another page anytime they arrived certain pages by clicking on back/forward buttons of the browser. I've found a [JavaScript solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54244573/9107694) as shown below. (This is a simplified example without mapping what URL to be redirected to.)

```js
if(is_safe(window.location.href))
    return;
if (window.performance.getEntriesByType("navigation")[0].type === "back_forward")
    window.location.href = "/Home.aspx";
```

That works fine, except it happens client-side, which is **after** `Page_Load`. **I want to avoid the entire `Page_Load` event, or at least be able to run only part of it if user arrives certain pages**, because many pages has `Page_Load` event that actually post database changes (I know... This is bad). Also, even if that is not the case, it'll be nice to avoid loading data when the user will be redirected to another page anyway.

How to achieve this goal?

---

**EDIT:** I didn't redirect or detect the navigation type from source when they click on the back button because [it is either impossible or very inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008806/how-to-detect-if-the-user-clicked-the-back-button). At some point when I haven't figure out this JavaScript solution, I've even tried to redirect the user twice, but wouldn't work because [browsers skips the redirect and post when back button clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60215022/auto-redirecting-page-is-skipped-by-chrome-history). If redirecting or detecting from source is possible, I would be more than happy to be corrected! The PRG pattern is complied to avoid double submit, but I don't think it's relevant here.

Comment: Are you just looking for [page lifecycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178472(v=vs.100)) events that occur before `Page_Load`?  Like `Page_Init`?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to access the user navigation type before or during `Page_Load`. I can't figure out how to get the user navigation type in `Page_Init` as well.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I'd be surprised if that information is even sent to the server, since the server doesn't really need to know it.  Taking a step back, what is the actual underlying goal here?  Why do you *need* to know the "navigation type" at all?  This sounds like an XY Problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out! I might not need to. I want to navigate the user away if they click on the back or forward button to arrive a certain page.

Comment: If that's truly needed then it sounds like it would need to happen client-side.

Comment: Yeah, the reason why its needed is provided in the question. I might be able to render a empty dummy page and trigger a post_back in the client, but I would prefer not to...

Comment: If by "the reason" you mean "avoid loading unnecessary data" then that's really still the "Y" part of the "XY Problem".  Perhaps the forward/back navigation can be interrupted on the source page, so they never navigate to the target page in the first place but instead navigate where you intend?  Perhaps you shouldn't be trying to interrupt forward/back navigation or other browser functionality in the first place?  Perhaps the whole thing can be architected in a more dynamic way to support whatever the underlying use case is?  Hard to say, but for the question asked "not possible" seems likely.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible to interrupted forward/back navigation on the source page (we can't even consistently know how the user leave the page), and like you said it's not a good idea to interrupt browser's functionality.

Comment: The reason is simply because we don't want some users to arrive some pages outside the normal flow determined by the application. I did think of having a whole navigation stack traced on the server side, and determine the valid paths, but that will be wayyy more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) is enough to achieve the goal (**If user arrives certain pages by back/forward buttons, avoid Page_Load events**). The key here is that modifying the URL of the current state using `replaceState` won't cause the page to reload based on the new URL. ([This is intended](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#can-have-its-url-rewritten), as the purpose of this method is to rewrite the document's attached URL to a target URL.) If placed in events such as `onbeforeunload`, the user will not see the URL being modified.

However, a big limitation of this approach is that if a user clicked on refresh, it will load the page based on the replaced URL. Since clicking on refresh counts as a postback, which can be detected by `!Page.IsPostBack` in `Page_Load`, this action could be allowed. This method sacrifices the ability to enable users to click on refresh and stay on the same page for those pages where the URL was modified.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  const unsafePages = {
    "/pages/unsafeOperation": "/pages/unsafeOperationList"
  }
  const currentPath = location.pathname;
  if (currentPath in unsafePages)
    history.replaceState({id: `${currentPath} replaced`}, "", unsafePages[currentPath]);
}
```